# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have documents like this in a couchbase DB

```
{

  "hostel": {
    "city": {}
    ...
  }
}
```

and I have this query defined in a repository

```
@Query("UPDATE #{#n1ql.bucket} SET hostel.state = $2 where hostel.id=$1 RETURNING #{#n1ql.bucket}.hostel    ")
Hostel update(String entityId, String newState);
```

but when I run it I got this error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: 
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.model.Hostel]
```

and the Hostel type:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Hostel {

    private @NotNull String id;
    private @NotNull String city;
    private JsonObject commodities;
}
```

I also tried with:

```
@Query("UPDATE #{#n1ql.bucket} SET hostel.state = $2 where hostel.id=$1 RETURNING #{#n1ql.bucket}.hostel    ")
void update(String entityId, String newState);
```

but then I got the error:

```
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Query returning a primitive type are expected to return exactly 1 result, got 0
```

Comment: Did you use `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)`

Comment: not available in the package org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.

Comment: The problem is in the return value `Hostel` because at the point of view of the Spring's deserializer, structure like `"name: {"key": value}"` is a `Map`. So first of all check your entity class `Hostel` for a properly annotated class and properties. And as a case you can create your own deserializer

Comment: @Sandro Rey please add a `@Field` annotation to hostel's properties and to a _hostel_ property in the `Bucket` entity as well. [Example](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Spring Data: Modifying Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods.at-query.modifying)

> You can specify the following return types:
>
> - void
> - int (updated record count)
> - boolean(whether a record was updated)

In your case you have return type `Hostel` what is not good if you are using `SpringData`. Spring can not convert result of query execution to `Hostel` type.
Try to use one of type specified earlier